# Evaluate $\int \frac {2x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+2)^2} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question :** Evaluate $$\int \frac {2x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+2)^2} dx $$

I am not able to find the value of the following integrals I tried with the method of **substituting** the denominator by $t$ but I cannot find the answer. Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with partial fractions?

Comment: I got it now by partial fractions I was making a calculation mistake thank you!

Comment: This integral is designed to give a nice partial fraction decomposition, so go for it, and please show some work..

Comment: Before you start partial fractions make the substitution $t=x^2.$ While doing partial fractions apply $${1\over (t+1)(t+2)}={1\over t+1}-{1\over t+2}$$ twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $t=x^2$ the integrand takes the form $$\displaylines{{1\over (t+1)(t+2)^2} =\left [{1\over t+1}- {1\over t+2}\right ]  {1\over t+2}\\ =
\left[ {1\over t+1}- {1\over t+2}\right ]-{1\over (t+2)^2}}$$ Thus the result is equal $$\log {x^2+1\over x^2+2}+{1\over x^2+2}$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Let $u = x^{2} + 1$. Then the proposed indefinite integral reduces to
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2x}{(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 2)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^{2} + 1)}{(x^{2} + 1)((x^{2} + 1) + 1)^{2}}= \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u(u+1)^{2}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts as follows

\begin{align}
&\int \frac {2x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+2)^2} dx 
= \int \frac1{x^2+1}d\left( \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}\right)\\
=& \ \frac1{x^2+2}+\int \frac{2x}{x^2+1}
-\frac{2x}{x^2+2}\  dx
= \frac1{x^2+2} +\ln \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}+C
\end{align}